# yacc: conflicts: 1 reduce/reduce

Tags: parsing, grammar, yacc, lex, text-parsing

In order to learn Lex/Yacc, I'm writing a CSV parser following the grammar specified on Page 3 of [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

I've run into a "reduce/reduce conflict," and I'm not sure how to progress. It seems to be a conflict between Rules 1 and 3 of my grammar, but I don't know of any other way to describe a CSV with or without a line break following the last record. Also, when I remove Rule 10 (the empty field rule) the reduce/reduce conflict disappears; however, I need to handle empty fields.

What is the issue with my grammar and how should I correct it?

### Yacc Source

```
%token COMMA
%token DQUOTE
%token CRLF
%token TEXTDATA

%%

file: records CRLF
    | records;

records: records CRLF record
       | record;

record: fields;

fields: fields COMMA field
      | field;

field: DQUOTE escaped DQUOTE
     | TEXTDATA
     | ;

escaped: escaped TEXTDATA
       | escaped COMMA
       | escaped CRLF
       | escaped DQUOTE DQUOTE
       | TEXTDATA
       | COMMA
       | CRLF
       | DQUOTE DQUOTE;
```

### `yacc -v` Output

```
State 14 conflicts: 1 reduce/reduce


Grammar

    0 $accept: file $end

    1 file: records CRLF
    2     | records

    3 records: records CRLF record
    4        | record

    5 record: fields

    6 fields: fields COMMA field
    7       | field

    8 field: DQUOTE escaped DQUOTE
    9      | TEXTDATA
   10      | /* empty */

   11 escaped: escaped TEXTDATA
   12        | escaped COMMA
   13        | escaped CRLF
   14        | escaped DQUOTE DQUOTE
   15        | TEXTDATA
   16        | COMMA
   17        | CRLF
   18        | DQUOTE DQUOTE


Terminals, with rules where they appear

$end (0) 0
error (256)
COMMA (258) 6 12 16
DQUOTE (259) 8 14 18
CRLF (260) 1 3 13 17
TEXTDATA (261) 9 11 15


Nonterminals, with rules where they appear

$accept (7)
    on left: 0
file (8)
    on left: 1 2, on right: 0
records (9)
    on left: 3 4, on right: 1 2 3
record (10)
    on left: 5, on right: 3 4
fields (11)
    on left: 6 7, on right: 5 6
field (12)
    on left: 8 9 10, on right: 6 7
escaped (13)
    on left: 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18, on right: 8 11 12 13 14


state 0

    0 $accept: . file $end

    DQUOTE    shift, and go to state 1
    TEXTDATA  shift, and go to state 2

    $default  reduce using rule 10 (field)

    file     go to state 3
    records  go to state 4
    record   go to state 5
    fields   go to state 6
    field    go to state 7


state 1

    8 field: DQUOTE . escaped DQUOTE

    COMMA     shift, and go to state 8
    DQUOTE    shift, and go to state 9
    CRLF      shift, and go to state 10
    TEXTDATA  shift, and go to state 11

    escaped  go to state 12


state 2

    9 field: TEXTDATA .

    $default  reduce using rule 9 (field)


state 3

    0 $accept: file . $end

    $end  shift, and go to state 13


state 4

    1 file: records . CRLF
    2     | records .
    3 records: records . CRLF record

    CRLF  shift, and go to state 14

    $default  reduce using rule 2 (file)


state 5

    4 records: record .

    $default  reduce using rule 4 (records)


state 6

    5 record: fields .
    6 fields: fields . COMMA field

    COMMA  shift, and go to state 15

    $default  reduce using rule 5 (record)


state 7

    7 fields: field .

    $default  reduce using rule 7 (fields)


state 8

   16 escaped: COMMA .

    $default  reduce using rule 16 (escaped)


state 9

   18 escaped: DQUOTE . DQUOTE

    DQUOTE  shift, and go to state 16


state 10

   17 escaped: CRLF .

    $default  reduce using rule 17 (escaped)


state 11

   15 escaped: TEXTDATA .

    $default  reduce using rule 15 (escaped)


state 12

    8 field: DQUOTE escaped . DQUOTE
   11 escaped: escaped . TEXTDATA
   12        | escaped . COMMA
   13        | escaped . CRLF
   14        | escaped . DQUOTE DQUOTE

    COMMA     shift, and go to state 17
    DQUOTE    shift, and go to state 18
    CRLF      shift, and go to state 19
    TEXTDATA  shift, and go to state 20


state 13

    0 $accept: file $end .

    $default  accept


state 14

    1 file: records CRLF .
    3 records: records CRLF . record

    DQUOTE    shift, and go to state 1
    TEXTDATA  shift, and go to state 2

    $end      reduce using rule 1 (file)
    $end      [reduce using rule 10 (field)]
    $default  reduce using rule 10 (field)

    record  go to state 21
    fields  go to state 6
    field   go to state 7


state 15

    6 fields: fields COMMA . field

    DQUOTE    shift, and go to state 1
    TEXTDATA  shift, and go to state 2

    $default  reduce using rule 10 (field)

    field  go to state 22


state 16

   18 escaped: DQUOTE DQUOTE .

    $default  reduce using rule 18 (escaped)


state 17

   12 escaped: escaped COMMA .

    $default  reduce using rule 12 (escaped)


state 18

    8 field: DQUOTE escaped DQUOTE .
   14 escaped: escaped DQUOTE . DQUOTE

    DQUOTE  shift, and go to state 23

    $default  reduce using rule 8 (field)


state 19

   13 escaped: escaped CRLF .

    $default  reduce using rule 13 (escaped)


state 20

   11 escaped: escaped TEXTDATA .

    $default  reduce using rule 11 (escaped)


state 21

    3 records: records CRLF record .

    $default  reduce using rule 3 (records)


state 22

    6 fields: fields COMMA field .

    $default  reduce using rule 6 (fields)


state 23

   14 escaped: escaped DQUOTE DQUOTE .

    $default  reduce using rule 14 (escaped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is, for example, `TEXTDATA CRLF`, it is unclear whether it should derive `file -> records CRLF` and then derive `records` to a single record or whether it should derive `file -> records` and then derive `records` to two records where the second contains only an empty field.

To avoid this ambiguity you can just remove the `records CRLF` alternative. Files ending with a `CRLF` will still be accepted - they'll be treated as having an empty field at the end.

If that's not what you want, you'll need to rewrite `fields`, so that the last record is not allowed to be empty (and then keep the `file: records CRLF` production).

PS: On an unrelated note, it seems to me that you should move some of your parsing work to the lexer, specifically the part where you parse the contents of quoted strings. Something like `"abc"` would be best handled by making the lexer turn it into a single token.